# How to pass link to javascript function via right-click menu?

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing, contextmenu, xul, add-on

I'm writing an add-on for Pale Moon web browser (Mozilla).

I have added the menu item to the right-click menu `contentAreaContextMenu`, which is the menu that appears when you right-click on a hyperlink.

My problem is that I don't know how to send the hyperlink to the called function.

I've tried:

```
oncommand="projectName.BrowserOverlay.sayLink(document.activeElement);"
```

But it returns an `[object XULElement]`, and the properties seem to only reference the add-on and not the link that was clicked on.

How can I pass the link that was right-clicked on to open the `contentAreaContextMenu` to the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to hack another add-on to find the answer.

Turns out I needed to call the function like this:

```
oncommand="projectName.BrowserOverlay.sayLink(gContextMenu.linkURL);"
```